# How are the Bits arranged in a QRcode?

Tags: qr-code

I've wondered how QR codes are working, so i did a research and tried to paint my own in an table in word.

On Wikipedia I found this picture

[image]

I understand the configuration, but how you actually store a letter doesnt make sense to me.

[image]

With the example letter w.

On even rows black is 0 and on odd rows 1.

So the example should give this binary number 01110011 which would be 115 but w is number 32.
So how do I get the right number

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about this topic but I found you a [video](https://youtu.be/KA8hDldvfv0) where dude explains it. And from what I understood, there are those **cells** that are read in order of numbers depending on arrow (there are 4 options here and you posted those yourself). So you simply follow those numbers and write 1s and 0s on paper which results in 8bit number. That video has much more detail.

It is also worth pointing out that it is MSB, meaning if we follow your example (you just considering numbers, not colors since you mislabeled it), it has arrow pointing up, meaning you write right/down to up/left which leads to number : `01110011` which has most significant bit at the left which means its 115

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little mistake in computing the code of the character.
Forget the odd and the even and just look at the color. From the bottom to the top you find from left to right the following sequence of the bits.
7 8
5 6
3 4
1 2
where 1 is the Most Significant bit.
So your character is 0111 0111 and not 01110011
0111 0111 -> 77 in hex and 0x77 is the ascii  code of w.